# Put Animation delay on ImageViews and TextViews that belongs to 1 Animation set

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have already a rough idea about how to do this and I think it is by making 2 or more animation set per Image View or Text View but the code would be to long. Is there a way in which I could minimize the codes? Here is the code for every Image View and Text View:

```
AnimationSet setA = new AnimationSet(true);

                fadeIn1.setDuration(1000);
                setA.addAnimation(fadeIn1);

                TranslateAnimation Trans1 = new TranslateAnimation(270, 0, 0, 0);
                Trans1.setDuration(1000);
                setA.addAnimation(Trans1);

                ImageView1.startAnimation(setA);
                //how do i place delay here??

                ImageView2.startAnimation(setA);
                //how do i place delay here??

                TextView1.startAnimation(setA); 
                //how do i place delay here??

                TextView2.startAnimation(setA);
                //how do i place delay here??


                setA.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                        ImageView1.clearAnimation();
                        ImageView2.clearAnimation();
                        TextView1.clearAnimation();
                        TextView2.clearAnimation();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make delay by using handlers..
eg:

```
               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     ImageView1.startAnimation(setA);

                }
            }, 2000);
          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     ImageView2.startAnimation(setA);

                }
            }, 4000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea I've already tried this but it doesn't work since the components as what I've said belongs to a single Animation Set so what this do is that it executes the animation again and again. At first execution the first View will do the animation and in second execution at 2000 milliseconds the first view will do the animation again but this time with the second view so on and so forth with the other 2 remaining views. I think everytime a certain animation set is being called the execution will repeat again and again.